# Webpack error parsing JSX file using Babel loader

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I tried to follow a tutorial to get react work and explore the great possibilties of this framework.

But while running `webpack` to bundle my react app, I encounter an error:

> ERROR in ./public/app.jsx
>
> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected character ' '
>
> ```
>    |   <Greeter></Greeter>,
>    |   document.getElementById('app')
> >  | );
>    |   ^
>    |
> ```

Here is the `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './public/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets:['react', 'es2015']
        },
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My file is a simple JSX, nothing fancy but displaying hello:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Greeter = React.createClass({

  // Render view
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello {/* Pass the function to child component */}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

let displayName = 'Galaxy';
ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeter></Greeter>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

My package.json file contains as dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
```

**Do I have an error in my webpack config?**

Comment: Do you get the same error if you remove `''` from your `extensions` array? Also, the code in the error does not match the code example you have given.

Comment: Sorry copy/paste mistake about the error code. Tried without `''` and still the same problem.

Comment: Gotcha. Could you try making a single row out of it? Might be an invisible character you have mistakingly pasted in. `ReactDOM.render(<Greeter></Greeter>,document.getElementById('app'));`

Comment: Omg... it works. I'm working with Atom on Debian and it appears to place unwanted characters anywhere. It messed up my package.json several times and I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack can't parse the unexpected character `' '`. You probably copied some code that contained characters that are not visible in your editor.

Comment: As stated in comment above, using Atom on Debian can make Atom create unwanted invisible characters. Thanks for cue.